# UISearchBar modifying its frame/bounds when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to place a UISearchController within my apps UI. The layout is:

- Yellow: a ViewController
- Red: another ViewController
- Black: a container within the YellowViewController

[image]

I want to put the UISearchView of the UISearchController within the black container.

My code is the following:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsViewController];
UISearchBar* searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
searchBar.frame =_searchBarContainer.bounds;
[_searchBarContainer addSubview:searchBar];
[_searchBarContainer layoutIfNeeded];
```

It places the UISearchBar in the correct place:

[image]

But when I select the search field it expands the bar over the container's bounds:

[image]

How can I solve that and avoid the size/appearance change when selected?

Note: Tried some options playing with the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and the  `clipToBounds` options with no success. I'm not an expert of iOS UI so I would appreciate an accurate answer. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed width or fixed max-width?

Comment: Try to set searchBar.frame before add searchBar to subview.

Comment: @SteeBono In the example code I'm setting the searchBar frame before :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my research, at each time you select `SearchBar`, a `UISearchController` is presented. This `UISearchController` always try to make `searchBar`'s width equals to `UIViewController` which is presenting `UISearchController`.

My solution is when `UISearchController` makes `SearchBar` has wrong frame, set `SearchBar`'frame again. You can try this code below.

```
@interface ViewController () <UISearchControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController* searchController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *searchBarContainer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsViewController];
  UISearchBar* searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
  self.searchController.delegate = self;
  searchBar.frame =_searchBarContainer.bounds;
  [_searchBarContainer addSubview:searchBar];
  [_searchBarContainer layoutIfNeeded];



}

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
  [searchController.searchBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
  [searchController.searchBar removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
  if (object == self.searchController.searchBar) {
    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size, _searchBarContainer.frame.size)) {
      self.searchController.searchBar.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;
      self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _searchBarContainer.frame.size.width, _searchBarContainer.frame.size.height);
    }
  }
}

@end
```

At least, it works :)

Or

- You can create another `UIViewController` which contains `SearchBar` after that add it to _searchBarContainer  if your case don't have any problem with this.
- Use `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` instead of `UISearchController`. It's easier to handle.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found useful infos.

There are several methods that are invoked when you tap the UISearchBar.
When some of this method are invoked, the frame of the `UISearchBar` change his value.

One of these methods try to fill the width equal to `UIViewController`.

Try to set your frame value inside one of these methods:

> searchBarTextDidBeginEditing
>   searchBarShouldBeginEditing

In this way you override the default value.

Bye