# SearchBar goes out of UINavigationItem frame when it is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller, titleview

I placed `searchController`'s `searchBar` in `navigationItem` as the `titleView` as follows:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Although it fits perfectly when it is not selected (cancel item is not shown), if it becomes first responder and cancel item appears next to the `searchBar`, it slides under of the `navigationItem` slightly. You can see the result below:

[image: Position of searchBar in navigationItem]

How can I fix this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.navigationItem.searchController` instead of `self.navigationItem.titleView`.

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
```

Learn more here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller

Comment: It only available for iOS 11 though

Comment: It creates a new line under navigationBar and show the searchBar there. I must show searchBar between quit and cancel items in one line as it shown in the figure.

Comment: Did you try to add self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

Comment: One more, you can try my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940042/uisearchbar-modifying-its-frame-bounds-when-clicked/46992046#46992046

Comment: @trungduc self.definesPresentationContext didn't affect the position of searchBar.

Comment: @DorukhanArslan Please take a look at the link in my above reply.

Comment: It's not working. As far as I understand, this is an iOS 11-specific case. Since searchController.searchBar's height is 56, it doesn't fit in navigation item with height = 44.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
     navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
}
```

Comment: See the comment I write for trungduc please.